# oracle container keeps restarting after i restarted the container by hand

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I have this oracle container based on the image `gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim`.

I use this docker compose file to run the container

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  oracle:
    image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      - oracle-volume:/opt/oracle/oradata
volumes:
   oracle-volume:
```

But when i restarted this by hand apparently the data files that were created are apparently missing and I get this error
`ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 20 - see DBWR trace file ORA-01110: data file 20: '/opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/dbs/{filename}.dat'`

And the container keeps restarting on its own.

Is there a way we fix this?